# Shiny:Cannot display vector of data defined in function called from server function

Tags: shiny

I am trying to display inn the GUI the vector defined in the external function.  The external function is called from the server function.  It does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

mainPanel(

 conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.pipe",
      helpText("YOUR PIPELINE"),
      textOutput("pipe")

    )
)

)


Value <- function(filename){
  pnames = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")

}


server <- function(input, output){
    output$pipe <- reactive({
    result <- Value(inFileName)
    pipeLine <- result$pnames
    output$pipe <- renderText({
      paste("Attention ", pipeline)
    })

    return(pipeLine)
  })
  outputOptions(output,"pipe", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function was not retuurning any values because it was defined outside the block were inFilename is defined.

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
    if(input$btn){
      hide("btn")
    }
    inFile = input$file
    inFileName = input$file$name
    if(is.null("inFile")){
      return()
    }
output$pipe <- reactive({

      result <- glycoPipe(inFileName)
      #pname <- c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")

      pipeLine <- result$pnames
      output$textBox <- renderText({
        paste("Attention ", pipeLine)
      })

      return(pipeLine)
    })
    outputOptions(output, "pipe", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  })
```